# How to get `wget` to use GET method to retrieve page requisites?

Tags: wget

I've got a simple command to get a logged in page with all its dependencies:

```
wget --post-data='user=user&password=password' --page-requisites https://…/login
```

The server log shows the following (abbreviated for obvious reasons):

1. POST /login 302
2. GET /account 200
3. POST /robots.txt 200 (should be a GET, but it succeeds, so no problem)
4. POST /favicon.ico 200 (ditto)
5. POST /[looong PageSpeed URL] **500 (for every CSS, JavaScript and image file on the page)**

GETting these files works fine, so the URLs are correct, but it appears PageSpeed doesn't like clients POSTing. **How can I make `wget` use GET for everything except the initial request?**

Using GNU Wget 1.18.

---

Update: [Bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51155) submitted.

Answer (score 2):

From 'man wget':

```
           This example shows how to log in to a server using POST and then proceed to download the desired pages, presumably only accessible to authorized
       users:

               # Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.
               wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
                    --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
                    http://example.com/auth.php

               # Now grab the page or pages we care about.
               wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
                    -p http://example.com/interesting/article.php

       If the server is using session cookies to track user authentication, the above will not work because --save-cookies will not save them (and neither
       will browsers) and the cookies.txt file will be empty.  In that case use --keep-session-cookies along with --save-cookies to force saving of session
       cookies.
```