# Can wget *print* the page dependencies URLs?

Tags: wget

As a possible work-around for [another issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/368536/3645), is it possible to make `wget` **print** the URLs it finds in the target document that **it considers as page requisites?** I'd rather not build scraping code for the simple task I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
wget -nv -p -nd --delete-after <url>
```

Which will output something like:

```
2017-06-01 21:37:41 URL:<url> [19101] -> "index.html.3" [1]
2017-06-01 21:37:42 URL:<url>robots.txt [24/24] -> "robots.txt" [1]
2017-06-01 21:37:42 URL:<url>rc/1502.css [19106/19106] -> "1502.css" [1]
2017-06-01 21:37:42 URL:<url>favicon.ico [5390/5390] -> "favicon.ico" [1]
2017-06-01 21:37:42 URL:<url>avatar/nopic.jpg [893/893] -> "nopic.jpg
```

That could be quickly converted or filtered to something that might suit your needs.